# delete grid row

Tags: php, grid, pagination

i have a simple grid with data from mysql db.

When delete a record actually refresh the page.

When i am at last page and start delete records after delete all records when refresh i get no data because i dont have any records on that page.

So some how i must find a way when i am on last page and all record deleted refresh to previous page.

Any ideas

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code where you get the current page, compare it to the max pages

```
$currentPage = (int) $_GET['page'];
$currentPage = ($currentPage <= $maxPages) ? $currentPage : $maxPages;
```

Comment: if($currentPage > $numOfPages)
{ header("Location: ?p=$numOfPages"); }
That did the trick.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do a simple count on the rows to be displayed.

```
if ($row_count == 0)
    ... redirect to previous page
```

make sure you allow for there actually being no records to be displayed on the first page.

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentPageNumber = $("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.page();

$("#GridName").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.page(currentPageNumber - 1);
```

Put above two lines after your delete logic is completed.
It worked for me